# Want to print return

Tags: java

This is my code, I just need to print the return value of the boolean expression. Overall what this should do is compare the second array to the first and determine if the second array ever appears within the first.

```
public class Contains {
   public static void main ( String [] args ) {
      int [] a1= {1,6,2,1,4,1,2,1,8};
      int [] a2= {1,2,1};
      contains (a1,a2);  
   }


   public static boolean contains ( int[] a1, int[] a2){
      int match = 0;
      if ( a1.length < a2.length ){
         return false;
      }
      for ( int k=0; k<a1.length; k++ ) {
         if ( a1[k] == a2[match] ) {
            match++;
            if ( match == a2.length) {
               return true;
            }
         }
         else {
            match=0;
            k--;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: You just need to print this: `contains (a1,a2);`? i.e., `System.out.println(contains (a1,a2));` ?

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(contains (a1,a2));`

This will print whatever is returned. No matter what the return type is.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the following code:

```
Boolean b = contains(a1, a2);
```

`b` is equal to the return value of `contains(a1, a2);`.
You can then print the variable `b`:

```
System.out.println(b);
```

You could shorten all this to simply:

```
System.out.println(contains (a1,a2));
```

It sounds like you didn't know how to set a variable to the return value of a function. Now you know!